# Why does a blank Android app take up storage and cache?

Tags: android, performance, caching

A blank Android app with a blank activity takes up storage space and about 1-2 seconds to cold load into memory. From the image below, you can see that the smallest app takes 1.27MB and 2.29MB of data. It also uses 9.47MB of cache! Does anyone know what the 2.29MB of data and 9.47MB of cache is? 
[image]